# Simples moving average error using the forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting, moving-average

When I try to forecast a time series with sma using the forecasting function I get this error:

```
fc <- forecast(sma(ts),h=3)
```

> Error: The provided model is not Simple Moving Average!

Anyone knows how to fix it?
The forecast is from the fpp2 package and the moving average function is from the smooth package.

This is an example:

```
library(smooth)
library(fpp2)
library(readxl)
setwd("C:\\Users\\lferreira\\Desktop\\FORECASTING") 

data<- read_xlsx("BASE_TESTE.xlsx") 
 ts <- ts(data$`1740`,start=c(2014,1),frequency=4)
> fc <- forecast(sma(ts),h=3)
```

> Error: The provided model is not Simple Moving Average!

Comment: What happens when you just do `sma(ts)`?

Comment: Same error : The provided model is not Simple Moving Average!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not reproducible because you have not provided the data.

The following example is reproducible, and does not give an error.

```
library(smooth)
forecast(sma(USAccDeaths))
```

Note that the `forecast` function being used here is *not* part of the fpp2 package. It is from the smooth package.

To check what's going on with your example:

- First check that your data is correctly read in.
- Then check that the `sma` function is returning something sensible. The error message suggests that the function is not returning the model it should.

Comment: Thanks for the support Professor.  1)First check that your data is correctly read in.(ok, it's in accordance with the rules) 2)Then check that the sma function is returning something sensible. The error message suggests that the function is not returning the model it should.(I have discovered that there is an incompatibility with the fpp2 library. if I compile for example the two lines below and only then compile the rest of the program it works!) library(smooth)
fc <-sma(airmiles,h=3)

Comment: Example : library(smooth)
fc <-sma(airmiles,h=3) #wait for compiling    library(smooth)
library(fpp2)
library(readxl)
setwd("C:\\Users\\lferreira\\Desktop\\FORECASTING") 

data<- read_xlsx("BASE_TESTE.xlsx") 
 ts <- ts(data$`1740`,start=c(2014,1),frequency=4)
> fc <- forecast(sma(ts),h=3)